# Connection refused: no further information when making a request in ktor

Tags: kotlin, jvm, ktor

```kotlin
 suspend fun callback(code: String, baseRoute: String): String {
        val body = Parameters.build {
            append("code", code);
            append("redirect_uri", baseRoute + REDIRECT);
            append("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        }

        println(body.toString())
        val response: HttpResponse = client.post("${BASE_URL}/api/token") {
//            contentType(ContentType.Application.FormUrlEncoded)
            headers {
                append("Authorization", "Basic ${encodedClientCredentials()}")
            }
            setBody(FormDataContent(body))
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
```

Routing:

```kotlin
        get("/token") {
            val baseRoute = call.request.headers["baseRoute"];
            val code = call.request.headers["code"];
            if (baseRoute == null || code == null) {
                call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Error");
            } else {
                call.respondText(api.callback(code, baseRoute));

            }
        }
```

when I make a request to /token I'm getting

> [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] DEBUG ktor.application - Unhandled: GET - /token. Exception class java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information]
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information

The callback method makes a request to Spotify API to get a token. Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Could you please try to make the same request with the `curl` from the development machine?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman Solved it. The problem was me not adding https to BASE_URL